# Is there a way to have a Tooltip for non-editable raster graphics produced by MakeBoxes?

Tags: front-end, undocumented, tooltip, boxes

I have a function which produces a large object I would like to hide. Formatting is of course an option but I'm hoping for something a little more meaningful using raster graphics and `Tooltip`.

Also, `Format` doesn't allow the object to be copied and pasted while retaining the internals of the object whereas `MakeBoxes` does.

Here is some sample code that produces what I want without the `Tooltip`.

```
f /: MakeBoxes[dat : f[args_], fmt_] :=
 TagBox[ToBoxes[Rasterize@RandomImage[1, {100, 100}]],
  InterpretTemplate[f[args] &], Editable -> False, Selectable -> True,
   SelectWithContents -> True]

f[1]
```

This produces the raster graphic with a `Tooltip` but the graphic is now editable/resizable.

```
f /: MakeBoxes[dat : f[args_], fmt_] :=
 TagBox[ToBoxes[
   Tooltip[Rasterize@RandomImage[1, {100, 100}], "tooltip"]],
  InterpretTemplate[f[args] &], Editable -> False, Selectable -> True,
   SelectWithContents -> True]

f[1]
```

Is there a way to have both a `Tooltip` and the non-editable raster graphic?

Comment: I always found the boxes stuff rather scary. There isn't really a thorough introduction into this matter in the documentation. [This one here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RepresentingTextualFormsByBoxes.html) doesn't really count as such. And now you're introducing the undocumented `InterpretTemplate`. Yikes!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Scary indeed but very powerful and often necessary :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My colleague John Fultz suggested the following answer.

```
f /: MakeBoxes[dat : f[args_], fmt_] := 
 TagBox[ToBoxes[Rasterize@RandomImage[1, {100, 100}]], 
  InterpretTemplate[f[args] &], Editable -> False, Selectable -> True,
   SelectWithContents -> True, Tooltip -> "tooltip"]
```

After a bit of exploring I realized that I should have checked the `Options` for `TagBox` all along.

```
Options[TagBox]

==> {AutoDelete -> False, BaseStyle -> {}, 
 DefaultBaseStyle -> {}, DefaultTooltipStyle -> "TooltipLabel", 
 DeleteWithContents -> True, DeletionWarning -> False, 
 Editable -> Automatic, SelectWithContents -> False, 
 Selectable -> Automatic, StripWrapperBoxes -> False, 
 SyntaxForm -> Automatic, TagBoxNote -> None, Tooltip -> None, 
 TooltipDelay -> 0., TooltipStyle -> {}}
```

Hopefully someone else finds this useful.