# Pasting TemplateBox with a Dynamic argument

Tags: front-end, boxes

Ok, this is pretty specific...

The objective is to use a `TemplateBox` to format something that is programatically inserted with `NotebookWrite`. That thing which is inserted is some dynamic control, an `OpenerBox`.
So, for example:

```
(*Pause[3];*)NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
 TemplateBox[{Dynamic[x]}, "blah", 
  DisplayFunction :> (OpenerBox[#] &)]]
```

Uncomment the `Pause[3]` to try it. Run it and select something in another input cell.

The problem is, in this example, that the `OpenerBox`doesn't open/close, or not until you convert the cell to cell expression and back to normal doing nothing, or until you cut and paste the `OpenerBox`, or until you write something in the cell expression, etc... Point is, the cell expression is perfect but it doesn't work until you slap the FE a little bit...

What's going on? How can I use a `TemplateBox` that gets pasted programatically to control some dynamic variable?

Comment: This seems to be an undocumented function, where did you find it? Name looks related to InterpretTemplate which Andy used in his [recent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3108/57) which also seems to be undocumented.

Comment: It is used plenty, very useful. In the Core.nb stylesheet there's a full (sub)section with definitions. I had found it first in http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8010/AdvancedTypesetting.cdf?file_id=7608. I don't know that InterpretTemplate, I'm taking a look, thanks

Comment: Wow, this is freaky.  While developing an answer for another question (which I hope will be really interesting) just last night, I tried to do *exactly* the same thing and made the identical discovery! I haven't had a chance to dig into the problem yet, but I will soon. Favoriting your question...and I'll swing back around when I have an answer.

Comment: @FredDanielKline That's not relevant to this discussion.  Sorry, I've been super-busy...I still intend to figure out what's going on here at some point.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pause[3]; NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
 TemplateBox[{Dynamic}, "Print", 
 DisplayFunction :> OpenerBox[(# &)]]]
```

Had to make name a valid function name.